# Region and Region Manager concept in UWP

Tags: wpf, prism, uwp, prism-6

For UWP development ,Prism 6 provides two  assemblies  Prism.Unity.Windows.dll and Prism.Windows.dll  but they would not support Region and Region Manager concept in WPF version of Prism .
As part of UWP App design ,we should identify pages and logic between navigation/updating of pages .We need to  make SessionStateAwarePage  for page base class and use INavigationService for naviagtion between pages .
will Prism team will support Region and RegionManager concept in UWP?? or should we live with Page and Page Navigation concept in UWP ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is already discussed [here](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/60).

Short answer:

> It is on our roadmap to integrate modularity and regions into the UWP platform version of Prism.